# SVR feature selection

Tags: r, svm, caret

I'm trying to go through feature selection with SVR (trough caret package in R). Working on a dataset with 400+ points and 20+ features and 2 target variable. Can I use correlation coefficient for that? I was thinking, first select features with high correlation coefficient with target variable, then check the correlation between features left and delete highly correlated ones.

Starting with 20+ features, I end up with only 3. Some features I originally thought should be very important are deleted.

The prediction accuracy is not that good, with normalised root-mean-square error over 15%.

Whether the feature selection process I describe above better for linear regression models? So it won't work very well with SVR when use RBF kernel?

Comment: What do you mean by "Whether the feature selection process I describe above better for linear regression models?"?

Comment: Feature selection of the following two steps, first select features with high correlation coefficient with target variable, then check the correlation between features left and delete highly correlated ones. Whether this process should not be use for SVR?

Comment: @AmyLee I don't know what you are doing, but it looks very wrong. What is your goal here? Why are you doing feature selection?

Comment: @user2974951 I want to select the most important features and eliminate the redundant features to speed up the model and avoid overfitting. Could you please explain a bit more detail about why the process are wrong? Thanks

Comment: Your approach is very arbitrary and I do not see a reason why it should work. I would try an established and formal feature selection method such as LASSO.

Comment: But correlation analysis seems to be one of the filter method for feature selection?see the link https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2016/12/introduction-to-feature-selection-methods-with-an-example-or-how-to-select-the-right-variables/

Comment: 20+ features sounds not too much. But if you want to select the best among them, maybe PCA will help: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.PCA.html